# Android admob ad on bottom below tabs in a tabview

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I have a tab layout like this:

### ------------------

### ------------------

{1}----[2]-----[3]

Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
>           
    <!-- Ad Placeholder -->
    <com.google.ads.AdView      
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="MYID"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

My 3 tabs are on the bottom. However my ad overlaps them, is there a way to put the ad right underneath the tabs?

Comment: maybe try put this stuff inside <TableLayout> it into <TableRow>?

Comment: what do you mean by this stuff?

Comment: put all components into one row, and the ads in another one or just take ads only to tablerow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [example](http://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/source/browse/adcatalog/res/layout/tabviewexample.xml?repo=ad-catalog-android) from AdMob's Ad Catalog sample application.  It involves wrapping the TabHost and ad around a RelativeLayout, aligning the ad to the bottom, and the TabHost above the ad.

You may want to take a deeper look at the sample application - it has other working examples on how to use AdMob in various layouts.